# Современные классики

Tags: литература

А кто и как решает, кого из писателей считать классиком? И есть ли современные классики литературы? Как я понимаю, популярный — еще не значит, что классик. Донцова тоже популярна в определенной среде.

[image]

Comment: Есть (или была) такая книжная серия: "Классики и современники". В её названии классики как бы противопоставляются современникам, делается намёк на то, что "современные классики" невозможны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Классик" - понятие неформализуемое и потому - в большой степени субъективное. Для меня "современных классиков" не существует, должно пройти время для признания автора таковым.

Comment: Почему комментарий? Это ответ на вопрос, есть ли современные классики. С мнением полностью согласна.

Comment: Даже не знаю, почему сделал сначала комментарием. Пусть будет ответом. Спасибо.

Comment: "Марк Из" а прокомментировать свой минус?

Comment: 3. Я не согласен с вашим мнением. Классик - это тот, на произведения которого ориентируются другие. Ориентирование складывается из популярности и степени новаторства. Если кто-то изобретёт новый жанр и его книги будут популярны, то он ещё при жизни станет классиком этого жанра.

Comment: Это не мнение. Это факт. Вы несогласны с тем, что *для меня* не существет современных классиков? Не предмет спора. Вы не можете знать лучше меня, что *для меня* существует, а что нет.

Впрочем, как скажете. Главное, что вы считаете возможным на подобных основаниях минусовать высказывания о собственным мироощущении. Я принимаю Ваши условия игры.

По сути - я тоже с Вами не согласен, тем более, что Вы даже не оговорили, что это Ваше личное мнение, а высказываетесь с претензией на объективность.

>Классик - это тот... 
Примеры современных, пожалуйста. Брежнев - классик?

Comment: 5. Я не согласен, что классик понятие неформализуемое. Трудноформулимое- да, но если есть понятие, значит и формализовать его возможно. Когда же вместо ответа дают- сие есть тайна великая, ибо не ведаем, что творим, то минус, по-моему, ответ вполне адекватный.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, из ныне живущих я бы назвала классиком детской (и не только!) литературы Владислава Крапивина.

Comment: Ну он-то по возрасту вполне может претендовать на это звание. 
Пятидесятилетие творческой деятельности отметил.
Вот заслужил ли - не знаю. Я как-то не проникся его творчеством.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что понятие "классик" определяется исходя не из возраста и творческого долголетия писателя, а по признакам следования определенным классическим канонам, восходящим к античным традициям (неслучайно классицизм как направление в литературе назвали так из-за возрождения традиций античной литературы), а также по уровню его художественного мастерства.В связи с этим мы писателя Боборыкина П.Д. не называем классиком, хотя он был самым плодовитым писателем 19 века.А вот М.Шолохова и при жизни называли классиком.

Answer (score 0):

О чём мы спорим? Чтение скоро (постепенно) уйдёт в небытие. Кто-нибудь из учёных-археологов в пыли архивов разыщет "классика" М. Шолохова, напишет от нём хвалебную статью - и только по этой статье народ будущего узнает о "классике". Однако читать всё равно откажется: потому что уж слишком древними и непонятными -на фоне окружающей действительности - окажутся описываемые события! "Сравнятся в славе смертью имена" (К. Симонов). Я тоже, как и @ виктор1799, считаю М. Шолохова классиком, но от нашего с ним мнения ничего не зависит. В принципе я согласен с [@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus), что классиков определяет время и что сейчас искать классиков - это то же, что искать талантливых методами "Фабрики звёзд"... О чём мы спорим, господа-товарищи, если мы уже и не те, и не другие?

Comment: Никогда чтение не уйдет в небытие. Чтение - способ общения,получения информации  и удовольствия.

Comment: Если бы Вы оказались правы!! Кто был бы против этого? Однако: чтение требует: 1)наличия хороших, грамотных воспитателей и учителей, которые приучили бы детей к чтению (но: родителям некогда, они заняты добычей куска хлеба; мы видим падение общего профессионального уровня воспитателей и учителей - в массе); 2) наличия свободного времени у самого объекта воспитания, если его"зажгли" страстью к чтению (но: уверен, что ему кусок хлеба придётся зарабатывать с ещё большими усилиями, чем его родителям); 3)чтение не престижно, не прибыльно, желающих читать - мало, их будет всё меньше!..Небытие!

Answer (score -3):

Мне кажется, есть простой формальный признак: наличие в школьных учебниках. Я, правда, давно не держал в руках школьные учебники. Но в советское время это был надёжный признак.

---

Ну, раз все остальные *согласны*, придётся самому себе возражать. Так или иначе в школьную программу попало достаточно много современников: Астафьев, Быков, Айтматов, Распутин, Вампилов, Евтушенко... А мы договорились (никто с этим не спорил), что современники не могут быть классиками. Значит, определять классиков по наличию в школьных учебниках нельзя.

---

UPD. В комментариях опять "переспам", отвечу здесь на вопросы [[[@grumant](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant).

1. Даты моей регистрации, начала моего реального присутствия на форуме и вашего скандала с Бегемотусом никак друг с другом не связаны, это случайное совпадение. Сразу после регистрации у меня не было возможности активно присутствовать здесь (было много работы).
2. На обращение "grumant" я не отвечал, потому что я "умнее". Или наоборот, тупой, как валенок. Я так до сих пор и не придумал, что в той ситуации вообще можно было бы ответить.

---

UPD2. Я теперь уже вообще не понимаю, зачем дополнял свой ответ объяснениями для [[[@grumant](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant), да и комментарии выглядят странно (ответы на какие-то несуществующие вопросы). Зато начинаю отчасти понимать [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus)'а: когда часть диалога внезапно куда-то исчезает (и ты начинаешь выглядеть дураком), это не может не раздражать.

[[[@grumant](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant), лучше всё-таки так не делать (не надо удалять свои ответы и комментарии, если это не требуется правилами форума или модератором).

Comment: Чтобы произведение попало в учебник, его тоже нужно отобрать. По определенным признакам, про которые и спрашивает автор вопроса.

Comment: Нет, автор спрашивает про признаки "назначения" классиков, а не про признаки отбора в учебник. Сначала мы должны согласиться, что это одно и то же (я выразил свою неуверенность словами "мне кажется"). Дальше, думаю, было бы искать ответ проще (принципы отбора в учебник всё-таки более формализуемы).

Comment: grumant, Автор не спрашивает про признаки назначения. Это Вы уже зря.

Comment: stopkran! Вы сами в своем ответе поставили знак равенства между классиками и авторами произведений в учебниках. А теперь придираетесь к словам.

Comment: @Ларf, я сомневался. Если бы вы развеяли мои сомнения, я бы начал думать дальше над конкретными признаками. Вы согласны с тем, что классиков можно вычислить по наличию в школьных учебниках?

Comment: >stopkran! Вы сами в своем ответе поставили знак равенства между классиками и авторами произведений в учебниках. А теперь придираетесь к словам.

Согласен!

Comment: Андрей Платонов или, скажем, Хлебников, в последнее время появились в учебниках. Видимо, стали классичными. Но это же во многом "политика"

Comment: Авторская песня тоже изучается в школе. При всем уважениии к Митяеву, нельзя сказать, что о н классик русской литературы.

Comment: @Лорана, а Высоцкий? или Матвеева?

Comment: С чего бы это?

Comment: @grumant, я не так близко знаком с вами, как вы с Бегемотусом, поэтому скажу менее фамильярно: назовите, пожалуйста, причину. Поймите, мне не жалко удалить, но ведь уже другие люди писали комментарии, старались... А если они будут против? Я, конечно, думаю, что всем пофиг. Но побаиваюсь. Лучше бы получить мнения в явном виде. Ну, или ваша причина должна быть **очень** убедительной.

Comment: >я не так близко знаком с вами, как вы с Бегемотусом  
  
Давайте не будем о личностях. Тем более, что я не имею чести быть с кем-то тут знакомым. Более того - решительно против каких бы то ни было личных отношений в виртуальном пространстве.

>и вашего скандала с Бегемотусом  
  
Я ни с кем не скандалил.  
  
А по сути - я поддерживаю. Манера удалять свой содержательный текст (тем более, если это влечет удаление и чужого), никак не сближает.  

Ну вот, grumant удалил свой пост. Не иначе как в желании выставить ответивших ему дураками.

Comment: Ваше форумное поведение, stopkran, дает мне основание считать **ваш аккаунт - клоном**. Всего хорошего, дальнейших успехов на ниве просвещения.

Comment: Чьим? Вы так яростно доказывали, что stopkran не Ваш мульт.
grumant, c какого ресурса вы принесли манеру называть мульта клоном?